# Laravel 5 with dsdevbe/ldap-connector Auth::check() returns false

Tags: php, laravel-5, adldap

I use dsdevbe/ldap-connector for Laravel authentication. For this purpose I used the default AuthController and added the postLogin method from AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers with following changes:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');

    if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials))
    {
        return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
    }

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
                ->withInput($request->only('username'))
                ->withErrors([
                    'username' => 'Benutzername oder Passwort falsch.',
                ]);
}
```

The `$this->auth->attempt()` works fine, when I use incorrect credentials I'm getting redirected to auth/login with an error. When I use correct credentials I'm getting redirected to /dashboard, but the sessions doesn't seem to work properly, because I get a reredirect to auth/login. When I try to `dd($this->auth->check());` the output is `true` before, and `false` after the redirect to dashboard.

Anybody know the issue and can help with that?

Sessions works well, tested with `session(['test' => true]);` under `attempt()` and with `@if(session('test')) {{ "works" }} @endif` in `auth/login` blade template.

Thanks.

Comment: for debugging purpose, try to change the session driver and the cookie name.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that tomorrow! Thanks for reply..

Comment: I've set the driver to cookie, but I didn't noticed any differences.

Comment: I've found a workaround by implementing the retrieveById() method under LdapUserProvider.php. You may want to take a look at https://github.com/JacksWastedLife/ldap-connector/blob/patch-1/src/Dsdevbe/LdapConnector/LdapUserProvider.php